# Difficulty with python recursion

Tags: recursion

Can someone explain why:

def sum_digits(n):
    if n // 10 == 0: return n
    else: return sum_digits(n // 10) + n % 10

print(sum_digits(137))

returns 11 and when i replace + with * it returns 1 instead of 21.

Comment: Maybe I misread your question; I thought you had a doubt about how the recursion works rather than a problem with the code.

Answer (score 0):

To find the sum of the digits of `137` we need to, quite plainly, take `1 + 3 + 7`.  The trick the recursion uses is to sum the mod 10 of the number, at each stage of the recursion.  To explain more visually:

```
input | input % 10 | remarks
137   | 7          | call sum_digits(13)
13    | 3          | call sum_digits(1)
1     | 1          | return 1, do not make more recursive calls
total | 11
```

When making each recursive call, we pass the input number divided by 10.  This removes the tens digit number which has already been summed, and shifts the remaining digits to the right by one.  When we hit a number less than 10, then the recursion ends, and we make no subsequent calls to `sum_digits`.